# What type should static member "reference" be if I create an iterator which modifies the value?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, type-traits

If I create an iterator which for example returns the value multiplied by two (*similair to boost::range::transformed*), what type should the iterator member typedef `iterator::reference` be if the value_type is an int?

As the returned value is an r-value, shall the `iterator::reference` be an `int`, or shall it still be an `int&`?

Answer (score 0):

If `reference` type doesn't make sense, don't provide it. After all, it doesn't make sense to provide something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hmmm [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01500_source.html#l00526) seems to provide a custom type `_Bit_reference` to overcome this problem for `std::vector<bool>`. Not sure it doesn't make sense in every case. It's probably a hack, though.